# How to combine Keras MNIST dataset with my own MNIST images?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, mnist

I created some MNIST digits by using a generative adversarial neural network and saved them in png format. I know that Keras has the MNIST dataset, but I want to combine the digit images that I created with the original MNIST dataset in the Keras. Is this possible, if so, how can I do this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

i'm pretty sure keras uses the lecun set found [here](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/)

just decode that set and add your own to the pile